# Reparametrize of cubic bezier curve in arclength

Tags: bezier-curve

I am looking for a way to re-parametrize the cubic Bezier curve in t domain to cubic bezier curve in S (arclength) domain. 
Thanks

Comment: @bubba, I also attempted this, but concluded it isn't possible. My application is to display SVGs on a laser scanner like you see at night clubs & laser shows. It has 2 rotating mirrors that steer the laser beam along the X & Y axis, so you need to feed it x,y coordinates moving at *constant* speed. Since cubic Bezier curves don't move at constant speed w.r.t.  t, so parametizing it by arc length is 1 way.  But a symbolic solution isn't necessary. All you have to do is to calculate ArcLength'[t] = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2] at each step and increment dt by the amount needed for constant speed.

Comment: I tried to find the cumulative arc length as a function of t in Mathematica, but it gave up after a few minutes of trying to evaluate the integral.

Comment: If you just need a rough result, you can approximate the Bezier curve by a polyline. Arclength parameterization of a polyline is easy. Actually, you can make the result as good as you want by adjusting the accuracy of the polyline approximation.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible (using rational functions, anyway). The only Bezier curves that can be parameterized by arclength  are linear ones (of degree one). See ...

```
R.T. Farouki, T. Sakkalis
Real rational curves are not unit speed
Computer Aided Geometric Design, 8 (1991), pp. 151–157
```

If you explain why you want to do this, perhaps there is some alternative solution to your problem.